# How to use page iterator in aws pricing boto3 api get products

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, pagination, boto3

How can I paginate results for iterating over aws pricing api to get prices?

Here is what I tried but getting error for no attribute '**getitem**'

```
pricing = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')
token = ''
paginator = pricing.get_paginator('get_products')
while True:
    response = paginator.paginate(
        ServiceCode='AmazonEC2',
        Filters=[
            {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Value': 'Linux'},
            {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'location', 'Value': 'US West (Oregon)'}

        ],
        PaginationConfig={
            'MaxItems':100,
            'PageSize':100,
            'StartingToken':token
        }
    )
    token = response['NextToken']
    print response.result_keys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you need to iterate using `NextToken`.

Here is an extract from [Paginating AWS API Results using the Boto3 Python SDK – aws advent](https://www.awsadvent.com/2016/12/21/paginating-aws-api-results-using-the-boto3-python-sdk/):

```
next_token = ''  # variable to hold the pagination token

while next_token is not None:
    results = pricing.get_products(..., NextToken=next_token)
    next_token = results['NextToken']
```

Comment: Thanks John, I figured this out using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201093/how-to-use-boto3-pagination. But I will mark your response as answer as well. Thanks for replying.