# How to get more than 1000 objects from S3 by using list_objects_v2?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have more than 500,000 objects on s3. I am trying to get the size of each object. I am using the following python code for that

```py
import boto3

bucket = 'bucket'
prefix = 'prefix'

contents = boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket,  MaxKeys=1000, Prefix=prefix)["Contents"]

for c in contents:
    print(c["Size"])
```

But it just gave me the size of the top 1000 objects. Based on the documentation we can't get more than 1000. Is there any way I can get more than that?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a daily listing of the bucket.

Answer (score 241):

The inbuilt boto3 `Paginator` class is the easiest way to overcome the 1000 record limitation of `list-objects-v2`. This can be implemented as follows

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='bucket', Prefix='prefix')

for page in pages:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        print(obj['Size'])
```

For more details: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to eval the current list of s3 buckets I have access to. I was wondering why they all had 1000 in them haha.

Comment: This is the ANSWER!

Comment: Is there an upper limit, since `pages` are in memory what if there are very large amount of objects.

Comment: I am curious about the possible difference between using `list_object_v2` and `list_object` when using the pagination wrapper.  Does `_v2` offer benefits in this case?

Comment: @ddttdd `pages` is an iterator and retrieves only one page at a time by following the continuation tokens (essentially a linked list), stopping when a page is retrieved that has no next continuation token

Comment: I want to retrieve all objects which was modified in last 24 hours, how can we add this filter on paginate result ? there might be more than 10000 objects in my bucket which  modified in last 24 hours.

Comment: @ShanDou I actually developed ListV2. The advantage of ListV2 is that your list will not timeout/fail when it encounters large batches of deleted (hidden) keys in a versioned bucket. However ListV2 should have been the default list method for some years now.

Answer (score 91):

Use the ContinuationToken returned in the response as a parameter for subsequent calls, until the IsTruncated value returned in the response is false.

This can be factored into a neat generator function:

```py
def get_all_s3_objects(s3, **base_kwargs):
    continuation_token = None
    while True:
        list_kwargs = dict(MaxKeys=1000, **base_kwargs)
        if continuation_token:
            list_kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(**list_kwargs)
        yield from response.get('Contents', [])
        if not response.get('IsTruncated'):  # At the end of the list?
            break
        continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')

for file in get_all_s3_objects(boto3.client('s3'), Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
    print(file['Size'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to distribute the creation of this list? Iterating through the generator to create the list takes hours.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 28):

If you don't NEED to use the `boto3.client` you can use `boto3.resource` to get a complete list of your files:

```
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3r.Bucket('bucket_name')
files_in_bucket = list(bucket.objects.all())
```

Then to get the size just:

```
sizes = [f.size for f in files_in_bucket]
```

Depending on the size of your bucket this might take a minute.

Comment: is there an advantage to using resource?

Comment: There are some methods that can be found in resource and not in client and vice-versa. However, in my experience they share a lot of the same functionality. You might be able to get the size of a bucket using client but I didn't find another way that was similar to this.

Comment: I am listing the objects in my path like this:

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
source_bucket_obj = s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket)
source_objects = source_bucket_obj.objects.filter(Prefix=source_key)

Are you saying that this will list all the files, even if there are more than 1000?

Comment: @MelissaGuo in my experience the `list(bucket.objects.all())` method returns all the files, even if its more than 1,000. Has that not been your experience?

Comment: Resources aren't thread safe, so if you're multi-threading you want to make sure to instantiate the resource individually. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html

Comment: after 3000 list, this fails

Comment: I used this and objects.filter to restrict the objects to a particular Prefix

Comment: @saviour123 Really? Isn't that a local limitation perhaps?