# boto3 - retrieve all buckets

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am trying to retrieve all buckets s3 via boto3 python. I have tried;

`s3_resource.buckets.all()` and `s3_client.list_buckets()`

both of these gives at most 1000 buckets but there are over 1000 buckets that I've found.
Is there a way to get all buckets?

I have also seen Java and C++ use an iterator to traverse through the list, is there something similar for python?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets

Using Paginator for list_buckets

```py
paginator = self.client.get_paginator('list_buckets')
pages = paginator.paginate()
```

> OperationNotPageableError: Operation cannot be paginated: list_buckets

About writing a custom paginator

`list_buckets` doesn't take in any request parameters.
Even the API call docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html
However in the response I see
`transfer-encoding : chunked`

I wonder if I can use that somehow?

Comment: similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314563/how-to-get-more-than-1000-objects-from-s3-by-using-list-objects-v2

Comment: @saranjeetsingh Thanks for your response. however, in the question you posted they are trying to list the objects in a bucket. I am trying to list all the buckets that are available

Comment: have you tried to create custom paginator? can you paste the exact error.

Comment: So I am not getting an error. It's just that I am limited to 1000 buckets (which makes me believe there is a limitation). I'll edit my question with the error in paginator

Comment: no paginator is available for list buckets. have to write custom one. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#paginators

Comment: Aah I see what you mean. `list_buckets` doesn't take in any request parameters. Even the API call https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html
However in the response I see `transfer-encoding : chunked`. Would you happen to know a good way to get the next set of results for this?

Comment: `transfer-encoding : chunked` is not relevant here. If `s3_resource.buckets.all()` and `s3_client.list_buckets()` would return string token called next_token in response then we can write custom paginator. next_token just tells us that there are more results are available to fetch.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you so much for all the help!