# How to get a total count of S3 Buckets with Python Boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I'm attempting to get a list of total amount of S3 Buckets on a given AWS account.

Using boto3 and Python 2.7, I have done the following:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
  bucket_names = (bucket.name)
  print bucket_names.count('\n')
```

However, this results in a 0 output for each line in bucket_names. Essentially, I'm trying to get the 'wc -l' equivalent if I were to do this in a nix shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use s3 client.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.list_buckets()

print(len(response['Buckets']))
```

Comment: Be careful, I think `list_buckets()` gets paginated.  This will probably work fine until the number of buckets fill the returned _page size_.  Then you'll eventually hit some strange issues and realize you're not getting all the buckets.

Comment: Take a look at this if you need to get _all_ the buckets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206941/24718

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain the number of buckets by using boto3 resource such a way,

```
import boto3

buckets = [bucket.name for bucket in boto3.resource('s3').buckets.all()]
print(len(buckets))
print('\n'.join(buckets))
```

where it will also prints the bucket names.