# boto3 pagination not returning all entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use boto3's pagination function to return all AWS IAM Policies. It seems like it'll return a number of them and then move on. If I run the script again it'll return the next batch etc

```
paginator = self.client_iam.get_paginator("list_policies")
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Scope="Local")

for page in response_iterator:
    for resource in page.get("Policies"):
      pass
```

As far as I was aware, this is all you need to do to paginate through all Policies, or am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Boto3 pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201093/how-to-use-boto3-pagination)

Comment: Your code should work. You sure that the missing policies don't have another scope?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to put a while loop for each pagination, Check this out: [How to use Boto3 pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201093/how-to-use-boto3-pagination)