# python boto3 pagination: aws workspaces

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am new to Python. I have a script (in AWS Lambda function) that loops over my AWS workspace items and prints out some info, however, it only prints out about 25 of the items instead of 200+ items. So I turned to paginators. But it is not working as the script is not printing out the info. Rather it is printing "uh oh".

Here is the script:

```
from pprint import pprint
client = boto3.client('workspaces')
final_detail = []
final_detail.append(['ComputerName', 'WorkspaceId', 'IpAddress', 'state', 'UserName', 'BundleId', 'WorkspaceProperties'])
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_workspaces')

try:
    for workspaces in paginator.paginate():
        for workspaceInfo in workspaces: 
        each_detail = workspaceInfo["ComputerName"], ["WorkspaceId"],["IpAddress"], ["state"], ["UserName"], ["BundleId"], ["WorkspaceProperties"]
        final_detail.append(each_detail)
#print(final_detail)

except = None
print(uh oh)
```

Comment: try printing the error message, except Exception as e: print(e)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Boto3 pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201093/how-to-use-boto3-pagination)

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee That prints out 'ComputerName'. Something is wrong with the second for loop?

Comment: Why are you iterating over `workspaceInfo["ComputerName"]`? That's a string containing the name of the computer for the current workspace. You should not be iterating over it. Perhaps you meant to iterate over a list of keys such as `['ComputerName', 'WorkspaceId', 'IpAddress', ...]` so you could get each attribute of interest.

Comment: Note that your exception handler is not as helpful as it could be. If an exception happens, you need to know what it was. Swallowing the exception and printing 'uh oh' is of limited help to you (or us).

Comment: @jarmod, yes! that is exactly what i want. But that still don't solve the TypeError: string indices must be integer problem. I am still getting the erroro even though i have changed it.

Comment: @jarmod, you are right, the code has been updated. Although still the same problem. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`workspaceInfo` is an iterator in your code, so you're accessing wrong object. This should work.

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_workspaces')
for workspaces in paginator.paginate():
    for workspaceInfo in workspaces['Workspaces']: 
        each_detail = workspaceInfo["ComputerName"], workspaceInfo["WorkspaceId"], workspaceInfo["IpAddress"], workspaceInfo["state"], workspaceInfo["UserName"], workspaceInfo["BundleId"], workspaceInfo["WorkspaceProperties"]
        final_detail.append(each_detail)
```

Comment: I got this error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers" on this line: each_detail = workspaceInfo["ComputerName"],["WorkspaceId"],["IpAddress"],["state"],["UserName"],["BundleId"], ["WorkspaceProperties"]

Comment: @John. That still does not help. Thank you though. I appreciate it. It looks like my workspaceInfo is a string, not a dictionary?

Comment: Okay, try this fix using `workspaces['Workspaces']` -- it's hard for me to debug because I'm not running any Workspaces.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yeah that does not work, mate.

Comment: To debug the situation, you should print `workspaceInfo` and see the content. You can then fix the code based on what you see.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, i see. So that actually printed "ResponseMetadata."